# SQL query is throwing this error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ' '

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Query is :

```
select * from Test.dbo.Test_Spoc where spocNo = 54986
```

In SQL 2008 its throwing error  Incorrect syntax near ' '. IF I remove the space before Where and again give the space its working.
In SQL 2012 this query is showing red sign also before Where that problem is in this space.

I want to know what can be reason that earlier space is not working?

Comment: Probably some "invisible" character resulting from copy & paste

Comment: It's probably not a space, but some other (non-printable) character

Comment: You can see that if you paste the query in Notepad++ for example and go to View/Show Symbol/Show All Characters

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from Test.dbo.Test_Spoc where spocNo = '54986'
```

Add single quotes, I think this might be the issue; you check the code

Comment: If `spocNo` is numerical, the quotes are not needed. They would just cause a conversion from string to numerical of the value (or if you are unlucky, the other way around on all values in that column)